# Moderncv -- I can't modify "Publication" section heading when I use with \bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

I am using `moderncv` and quite like the result.

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.

%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
```

I can set all the `\section{names}` except for `\section{Publications}` when I include the following code:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % 

\bibliography{Citations.bib} %

\nocite{ref1, ref2, ref3} % pull in just these publications

\end{document}
```

Somehow this code implements `\section{Publications}` on its own. Not sure where -- haven't been able to figure that one out!

However, I really want a section named "Selected Publications".

How do I get that?

Comment: Probably `\renewcommand\refname{Selected Publications}` gves what you want.

Comment: leadriis -- many thanks that's solved my problem. Voodoo. I will have to lookup that command!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the wod "Publications" to "Selected Publications" you can use:

`\renewcommand\refname{Selected Publications}`